# How to link libraries in CLion?

Tags: c, linker

I've been at this problem for a while now and couldn't find anything to solve my problem. I'm trying to use the ncurses.h library in my program but the linker failed and told me that I had undefined symbols. I fixed that by creating a new folder called **includes** and copying the location of ncurses.h from `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/ncurses.h` to the new folder. Then I put this line into my CMakeLists.txt file: `target_link_libraries(<project name> includes/ncurses.h)`. But then I got another error saying `ld: library not found for -lincludes/ncurses.h`. I've tried using `add_library()` but that gave me an error saying:

```
The target name "includes/ncurses.h" is reserved or not valid for certain
  CMake features, such as generator expressions, and may result in undefined
  behavior.
```

Does anyone have any other suggestions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CMake can't find Curses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4678926/cmake-cant-find-curses)

Comment: @jordanvrtanoski none of the solutions in that question answer mine. There's nothing out of the ordinary when updating the cmakelist.txt file except for the same `ld: library not found error` when building the program

Comment: I will post short working example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the location of the `ncurses` library, you will need to use the `find_package()` to locate the `Curses` package. The `find_package()` will return the `CURSES_INCLUDE_DIR` and `CURSES_LIBRARY` environment variables with the location of the include files and library.

Following is minimal example that works in CLion on macOS with:

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.9)
project(test)

find_package(Curses REQUIRED)
include_directories(${CURSES_INCLUDE_DIR})

add_executable(test test.c)
target_link_libraries(test ${CURSES_LIBRARY})
```

**test.c**

```
#include <ncurses.h>

int main()
{
    initscr();          /* Start curses mode          */
    printw("Hello World !!!");  /* Print Hello World          */
    refresh();          /* Print it on to the real screen */
    getch();            /* Wait for user input */
    endwin();           /* End curses mode        */

    return 0;
}
```